# Storing date time in java elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am trying to store the date time of an entity that is being created. I used `org.joda.time.DateTime.now()` to create a `DateTime` object. But it gets stored in the elasticsearch as

```
{"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2016,"yearOfCentury":16,"weekyear":2016,"monthOfYear":5,"weekOfWeekyear":18,"hourOfDay":15,"minuteOfHour":25,"secondOfMinute":28,"millisOfSecond":431,"dayOfYear":128,"year":2016,"dayOfMonth":7,"dayOfWeek":6,"era":1,"millisOfDay":55528431,"secondOfDay":55528,"minuteOfDay":925,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"America/Los_Angeles"}
```

is there a way to specify a format in which the object gets stored like `May 07 2016 14:58:44`? If we store it as strings would we still get the performance advantage of doing range queries?

Answer (score 0):

Go on the doc and try to formate your date ;)

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html

Comment: so specifically, is there a format that elasticsearch expects that helps queries run faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use toString() method with a format string:

```
String dateStr = datetime.toString("dd:MM:yy");
```